# "No spec found" is displayed after I use one jasmine reporter

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am using jasmine-node framework for my API automation. I am able to run REST services and able to get the result using node-fetch or http. Without reporter when I run with the below command I was able to get the results in console

```
jasmine spec/xxx.spec.js
```

After that I added a reporter(pretty html reporter) for reporting. Now when I run those commands, I get the below error.

```
No specs found
```

Below are my code for reporter.js

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var HtmlReporter = require('jasmine-pretty-html-reporter').Reporter;
var path=require('path');
var jasmine = new Jasmine();

jasmine.loadConfigFile('./spec/support/jasmine.json');

// options object
jasmine.addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
  path: path.join('./spec/helpers','results')
}));

jasmine.execute();
```

and jasmine.json is below

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": true
}
```

Please help me with this. Also please let me know if there is any better reporter than this.Thanks in advance

Comment: @JJones  can you please help?

Comment: @scipper can you please help?